# ¿como redireccionar http hacia un https en .htaccess en debian vps?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, ssl, vps, debian-9

Actualmente estoy tratando de aplicar mi SSL en mi sitio web que de hecho ya esta activo pero solo si entro directamente con https://dominio.com sale el candado de seguridad.

pero si solo pongo `www.dominio.com` , `dominio.com` o `http://dominio.com` no me sale el candadito ver en el navegador.

ya hice un `.htaccess` en mi document root que es en esta ruta `/var/www/html`  y dicho archivo tiene el siguiente código.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redireccionar a https cuando tiene www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redireccionar a https con www cuando no tiene https ni www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.tupagina.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redireccionar a www cuando tiene https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.tupagina.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

ejecute la sigueinte linea `sudo a2enmod rewrite` y reinicie el servidor de apache con `sudo service apache2 restart`.

y aun con todo eso no me redirecciona a https en la tres opciones que busco redireccionar, sabrán a que se pueda deber o si me falta configurar algo mas.

Comment: ¿Y porqué en vez de `.htaccess` no usas un `redirect` en el archivo de configuración del sitio?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de modificar el archivo host o el servidor DNS.

El archivo de hosts en ese sistema se encuentra en la ruta `/etc/hosts`. Al igual que en Windows, es un archivo de texto que podremos editar como superusuario con cualquier editor.

Así podremos acceder como superusuario de forma sencilla.

Abres el archivo `/etc/hosts`  en el editor que desees. Por ejemplo, si usas VIM, podrás abrirlo con el comando

```
vim /etc/hosts
```

Editas y salvas de forma habitual.
Otra alternativa es con el comando:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Suerte!